# how to position multiple views in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use ionic Framework to build a content menu which has 2 parts, coming from different controllers. I have specified them as `view: menuContent` and `view: menuSubcontent` below.

HTML

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="main bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon"></i></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuSubcontent"></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
        </header>
        <ion-content class="has-header">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="login()">
                    Login
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/morestuff">
                    etc.
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

ROUTER

```
.state('app.playlists', {
    url: "/playlists",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/playlists.html",
            controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
        },
        'menuSubcontent': {
            template: "<span>subcontent of playlists</span>"
            }
        }
    })
```

When the page renders, the `<ion-nav-view name="menuSubcontent">` is not visible although it is in the DOM. I added some CSS properties to make it visible:

```
z-index: 2
margin-top: 400px; /* some arbit large number */
```

I was wondering if this is the right approach (adding my own css classes to menuSubcontent) or is there systematic way of using the framework which takes out the *guesswork* in positioning with multiple views. I am still learning how to use this framework.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: A codepen might help make it easier for the rest of us to experiment with the problem and make some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-side-menus ng-controller="SideMenuController">

  <!-- Header Changes -->
  <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">

      <!-- Open Sidebar Menu Start-->
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <!-- Open Sidebar Menu End -->

      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
        <i class="ion-chevron-left"></i> Back
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <!-- Open Sidebar Menu Start-->
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-refresh" ng-click="doRefresh()"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <!-- Open Sidebar Menu End -->

    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view name="main" animation="slide-left-right">
    </ion-nav-view>

  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <!-- Header Changes -->

  <!-- SideMenu Contents -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left" class="light-bg dark-border">

    <header class="bar bar-header bar-light">
      <h1 class="title">Route Menu</h1>
    </header>

    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <div class="list">

        <a menu-close class="item item-icon-left" href="#/app/home">
          <i class="icon fa fa-bank fa-ionicon"></i>
          Home
        </a>

    </ion-content>
    <!-- SideMenu Contents -->
  </ion-side-menu>


</ion-side-menus>



    //** abstract route for sidemenu
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/sidemenu.tpl.htm'

    });

    //!** Home
    $stateProvider.state('app.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'main': {
          templateUrl: 'app/home/home.tpl.htm'
        }
      }

    });
```

Define your template as abstract in your routes :
Sources : http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/vqhzt

Answer (score 0):

If you keep multiple  in same page then you have to configure like below,

```
<ion-tab title="Rooms" icon-off="ion-ios7-box-outline" icon-on="ion-ios7-box" href="#/tab/rooms">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-rooms"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Chat" icon-off="ion-ios7-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios7-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chat">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chat"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

So based on url appropriate view will get render,

Else you can create separate state for each view like below,

```
.state('menuLogin', {
url: '/menuLogin',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/loginMenu.html'
```

})

```
.state('menuMain', {
url: '/menuMain',
cache:false,
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/mainMenu.html'
})

.state('menuLogin.login', {
url: '/login',
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  }
}
})

.state('menuMain.main', {
url: '/main',
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  }
}
})
```

So first state is belongs to login menu and second is belongs to main menu.

Loginmenu.html :

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
<ion-nav-back-button class="no-text">
</ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" align-title="center"></ion-nav-view>
```

and Mainmenu.html :

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center" style="text-align:center;">
<ion-nav-back-button class="no-text">
</ion-nav-back-button>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" align-title="center"></ion-nav-view>
```

So you can customize state like this.

Hope this helps you.